# Como adicionar configuraçoes de proxy tor no navegador chrome com c# e selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Preciso abrir o navegador chrome com configurações de proxy do Tor usando o selênio. Obtive exito com o firefox porem é pouco ágil, então é preciso usar o chrome. O problema é que não sei como aplicar as configurações para o chrome.

Preciso de uma solução funcional para o cromedriver.

no firefox fiz assim, este metodo é chamado apos o TOR BROWSER ser aberto:

```
private void ConfigureBrowser()
        {
          Logger.Log($"{Logger.MethodName()} -- Configurando Firefox...");
            try
            {
                var ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                ffOptions.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
                ffOptions.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
                ffOptions.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
                ffOptions.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;

                var t =  @"WebDrivers\";
                Logger.Log($"{Logger.MethodName()} PATH GECKO -> {t}", ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta);
                this.DRIVER = new FirefoxDriver(t, ffOptions);
                this.Wait = new WebDriverWait(this.DRIVER, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80));
                Logger.Log($"{Logger.MethodName()}  FIREFOX OK", ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Log($"{Logger.MethodName()}  ERRO AO INICIAR FIREFOX -> {e.ToString()}", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depois de muita pequisa consegui resolver meu problema que era mais simples do que eu imaginava, pois agora intendi como funcionava a configuração de portas, opções customizadas e ip local host do tor proxy no selenium usando proxy tor e navegador chrome.

segue abaixo meu método de configuração:

```
    public ChromeOptions GetDriveOptions()
    {

        var options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
        options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", PathDowload);
        options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");

        if (HeadLess)
            options.AddArgument("--headless");

        if (UseTor)
            options.AddArgument("--proxy-server=socks5://" + "127.0.0.1" + ":" + "9050");

        options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;

        return options;
    }
```

utilizo um container docker para rodar o tor proxy e passo um ip localhost junto com a porta que o docker expoem para o cliente, com o container iniciado eu chamo este método acima para aplicar as configurações de proxy e outras adicionais como modo de exibição do browser com janela e sem janela onde executa todos os processos sem uma interface, após tudo isso retorno um objeto chromeoption e aplico ao meu driver.